# creating mysql schema from pojo with hibernate using netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I have been fortunate in finding some good tutorials on how to create POJOs from database schema using hibernate (e.g. http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html).

Does anyone know of tutorials on creating database schemas from POJOs -- preferable using netbeans? Even the very smallest tutorial with one table or two related tables will do.

Answer (score 0):

Generating schema from Hibernate is actually built into Hibernate itself.  I'm not sure if there is a GUI for this, but all you need to do is just add a line to your configuration file. Start by add a configuration value to whatever you are using to your Hibernate configuration. For example:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Other [configuration values](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/apa.html#d5e4731) include `update`, `validate`, and `create-drop`.

You can [customize the generated schema](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html#d5e339) quite a bit.